# php returns empty JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I created an array for town name, "Auckland" and "Hamilton", but the response from php is always empty, any idea?

UPDATE: 
after debugging, I found that the problem is in php query
" where town = '$town' ", once i deleted this line, the rest works perfectly.
But I still can't figure out why :<

javascript:

```
 var _addNewTowntoList = function(){
     if (_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (_request.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(_request.responseText);
                if(data.length == 0){
                    alert("No such town");
                    return;
                }

                 var t = data[0].town;
                 var o = data[0].outlook;
                 var min = data[0].min_temp;
                 var max = data[0].max_temp;    

                 var witem = new WLine(t,o,min,max);
                 console.log(t+" "+o+" "+min+" "+max);
                 _list.push(witem);
             }
         }
 }
```

here is the php

```
   $town = $POST_['town'];
   $query = "Select * From weather WHERE town = '$town'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
   //create array for data
   $data = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {

        $data[] = $row;
   }
   echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: how you are calling this php page? i am unable to see any code regarding calling?

Comment: ` $town = $POST_['town'];` - typo in the variable name `$_POST`?

Comment: yes, there is another javascript function creating xml request: var _addNewTown = function(town){
 
  //create AJAX request, send town name to php
  _request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "./PHP/weather.php";
  var data = "town="+town;
  _request.open("POST",url,true);
  _request.onreadystatechange = _addNewTowntoList;
  _request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  _request.send(town);
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
$town = $POST_['town'];

>  $query = "Select * From weather WHERE town = '$town'";
```

to

```
 $town = $_POST['town'];

 $query = "Select * From weather WHERE town = '".$town."'";
```

Comment: opps i didnt notice this error, somehow it is getting the correct value, but it still returns empty string

Comment: Here you are replacing the data array every time loop runs at the end of the loop it will be empty so it is returning the last value instead you push the row in to data array...

Comment: mysqli_fetch_all($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
Try this function

Comment: yeah, i tried it still returns an empty string, but once I deleted the "where town ='$town'", the whole ajax works.   looks like the comparison is where the problem occurred.

Comment: @YouyouGao if that is the case you have to check the `$town` value because it is not matching the any records ..............

Comment: @YouyouGao try like this if you are using the `php < 5.4` you cannot make use of the `[]`  so try like this for data ...   `$data = (array)$row;`

Comment: thank you very much, it s all sorted!! somehow I cant use the POST method, when I changed it to GET, it works fine!!!! thank you again for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Remember to [properly escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) the query string

```
$town = mysqli_real_escape_strin($conn, $_POST['town']);
```

Because else your script is opened to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack

The other thing to mention here other than correct name for the [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is that you can use [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) function to fetch all results at once and avoid the loop. For example

```
echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```